# Qt QString lastIndexOf not working

Tags: c++, qstring, qt5.6, lastindexof

I'm using Qt5.6, I'm trying to use the QString function lastIndexOf.  The subject data contains something like:

```
    156 + (28 * 4) + (14 * 9 * 2)
```

Using indexOf:

```
    int intOpB = strLocalCopy.indexOf(ucOpenBracket);
```

strLocalCopy contains the subject data and ucOpenBracket contains '('.

intOpB is returned correctly and is 6.

I then look for the last occurence of ')':

```
    int intClB = strLocalCopy.lastIndexOf(ucCloseBracket, (++intOpB));
```

Using intOpB as a reference, but lastIndexOf is always returning -1 to intClB, why?

I'm using the debugger to single step so I can verify that all variables contain what they should.

If I remove the 2nd parameter it works, but I don't understand why it doesn't work with the parameter supplied.

Comment: This applies to 5.6 if you're like me using it in 2022. It's a good idea to use string.lastIndexOf(pattern, -1, cs), including all the parameters. Using only lastIndexOf(pattern) or .lastIndexOf(pattern,  cs) seems to fail in some cases hard to identify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#lastIndexOf):

> int QString::lastIndexOf(const QString &str, int from = -1,
>   Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = Qt::CaseSensitive) const
>
> Returns the index position of the last occurrence of the string str in
>   this string, searching backward from index position from. If from is
>   -1 (default), the search starts at the last character; if from is -2, at the next to last character and so on. Returns -1 if str is not
>   found.
>
> If cs is Qt::CaseSensitive (default), the search is case sensitive;
>   otherwise the search is case insensitive.

So the search starts from position 7 and searches BACKWARDS for the last occurence of ')', which at that point there are none between positions 0-7 on the QString